# Lyrics for the rap in "She Drives Me Wild" by Michael Jackson

Tags: lyrics, michael-jackson

This is regarding the song *She Drives Me Wild* from the album [*Dangerous*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangerous_%28Michael_Jackson_album%29) by Michael Jackson.

I have checked in many places on the Internet but the lyrics for the rap portion in this song are not published anywhere (including the CD sleeve).

1. Is there a reason for that?
2. What are the lyrics for the rap portion in the song?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partial answer. I assume the rap portion you're referring to is part:

> Please, no, keep back, I can't take it / You're drivin' me wild / I
>   might not make it / You got me lookin' like buckwheat, oh / Hair
>   pulled every which way but me / Far from Medusa, but your looks are
>   deadly / You're walkin' soft, still I hear the medley / Uh, shiver my
>   timberland boots, cramped my style / She drives me wild ([source](http://genius.com/Michael-jackson-she-drives-me-wild-lyrics/))

As for why it's not been officially released... I have not been able to find any definitive  information. My *guess* (based only off of personal observations) is that it's due to the Rap being performed by a different artist (Aquil Davidson), and publishing issues related to that.

Comment: Ah thanks for the lyrics @Lin. Heavy-D rapped in the same album in the song Jam which didn't seem to have a problem being published. I've always wondered if Aquil got dropped from being credited by mistake.

Comment: the first part remaining unanswered. But I suppose this will have to do for now.